# Does halacha demand that we change the name of a departed woman?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I have had the chance to meet the grandmothers of many of my friends and they have had a variety of names. And yet, when I speak with my friends after their grandmothers have passed away, they all say the same thing:

"My grandmother, Leah Hashalom..."

Is there a practice that requires that we change the name of grandmothers after their death to Leah Hashalom? Does this apply to other elderly women?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, ALL women get the name "Le'ah Hashalom" after they die, not just grandmas! But, let's focus on grandmas, shall we?

All grandmas are much like Le'ah. The "original" Leah suffered so much in her life. She cried because she thought she would have to marry Esav, as she was the older. Then, her father does the switch and bait with her sister and she is forced to go along with it. Her new husband (Jacob) prefers her sister and doesn't lover her the same way. Her daughter gets raped. Her kids sells Joseph as a slave ...  How much suffering can she take, really? Yet, for the most part, she keeps quiet, and deals with all of this. Finally, when she dies, it is HER that gets buried with Jacob and not Rachel, her "rival". She finally has some peace and rest only after her death.

Think about Jewish grandmas, these days. They spoil their grandkids. They have to compete with the "other" grandma over who gets the grandkids for Pesach Seder this year. Sometimes the grandkids call grandma; often they don't. WHen the grandkids come to grandma, they're sometimes messy and grandma can't bend down so well to clean up the mess! Then, when grandma gets older, she moves to Florida while the grandkids live in Israel. So, how often does she get to see them? Oy! So much suffering, just like Le'ah.

So, you can see the comparison, here. So, in honor of Le'ah, halacha suggests that grandmas get her name.

I'll have to research why other women get that name, too. My grandma (her name was NOT Le'ah, BTW, but, I guess "Pola" is close!) used to tell me how much suffering childbirth is. Maybe, that's reason enough to have all women named after Le'ah.